# Django attribute module OS

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to intall Vataxia social network platform on my local windows machine, but I'm receiving message like.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\rade\desktop\vataxia\back\env\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-mb9x0ep8\\uWSGI\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Wondershare\\CreatorTemp\\pip-install-mb9x0ep8\\uWSGI\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-mb9x0ep8\uWSGI\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-mb9x0ep8\uWSGI\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import uwsgiconfig as uc
      File "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Wondershare\CreatorTemp\pip-install-mb9x0ep8\uWSGI\uwsgiconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
        uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
    AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of `Python` you are using and which `command` gave that exception?

Answer (score 0):

`os.name` method is Python port of the specific *nix command, you can't get it in Windows. Either you should download a MS Windows version or, more likely, you can't run that software in Windows.

Try in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

`os.name` is [only available on Linux machines.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.uname)

The software you are looking at, or at least one if it’s dependencies, cannot be run on Windows without changing the code of the software.

I did some Googling and found that you are probably cloning a git repository to get this. Try substituting `platform.system()` for `os.name`.